# How to use detalization queries in apollo graphql reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

Suppose `data` - is data from a parent query.

Child react-component:

```
const ShowDetails = ({data}) => {
   const { loading, error, data_details } = useQuery(someQueryAsksAdditionalFileldsForEntryAlreadyPresentInCache);
}
```

`someQueryAsksAdditionalFileldsForEntryAlreadyPresentInCache` -- asks for additional fields that are missing in `data`.

When `(!loading && !error)` `data_details` will have requested fields.

Issue: `data_details` will have only requested fields.

**Question:** Is there a way to use parent data with merged-additional-requested fields in ShowDetails and ignore `data_details`?

In Chrome with help of Apollo devtools I see that apollo-cache has one entry from merged `data` and `data_details`.

I do not want to re-fetch all existed entries in `data`.

Example:

Parent component query:

```
const bookQuery = gql`
  query ($bookId: ID!) {
    book(id: $bookId) {
      id
      author
    }
  }
`
```

Details query:

```
const bookEditionsQuery = gql`
  query ($bookId: ID!) {
    book(id: $bookId) {
      id
      editions {
        publisher
        year
      }
    }
  }
`
```

```
const bookReviewQuery = gql`
  query ($bookId: ID!) {
    book(id: $bookId) {
      id
      review {
        user
        score
        date
      }
    }
  }
`
```

All this queries will populate the same bucket in Apollo cache: `book` with `id`.

What is necessary to achieve: in react component `BookDetails`:

have 1 object with:

`data.author`
`data.editions[0].year`
`data.review[0].user`

Logically - this is one entry in cache.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: no need to merge / passing from parent ... just query for ALL required fields using cache-only policy

Comment: This does align with [this](https://spectrum.chat/apollo/apollo-client/what-is-the-difference-between-readquery-and-usequery~3741a4a2-eaf6-4d12-b8de-cfa4d3f3933a?m=MTU5NjE3NzI0NTcxNw==)   
@xadm: quote from the link:  There are different fetch-policy which you can use when firing the graphql queries . when fetch policy is set to fetchPolicy: 'cache-only' . You are saying that ,
This fetch policy avoids making any network requests.If the data you are querying is not available in the cache, it will throw an error.

Comment: I think `cache-first` also will not help :  If the cache is missing some of the data you asked for, Apollo will make a network request to your API according to query - this means re-fetch all fields.

Comment: if not all already in cache then you can merge using onCompleted

Comment: Merging two data is not easy. The two queries `parent` + `details` can have specific set of fields. Example parent have: '{ book { author }}' details_query '{book {editions { year}}}' . Merging two object with the same set of keys something not easy.

Comment: you're expecting some magic or AI ... just fetch details or provide more specific details/example/problem

Comment: @xadm I added an example to the question body. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost nothing to save by using already fetched [and passed from parent] data ... only `author` ... all review and edition must be fetched, no cache usage at all.

... fetching `review` and `editions` by `book` resolver helps apollo cache to keep relation but also requires API to use additional ('book') resolver [level] while it is not required ... review and editions resolvers should be callable directly with book id ... and f.e. can be used by separate `<Review />` sub component ... or `review` and `editions` called within one request using the same id parameter.

Just use `data` and `dataDetails` separately in component - avoid code complications, keep it simply readable:

```
const ShowDetails = ({data}) => {
   const { loading, error, data:dataDetails } = useQuery(someQueryAsksAdditionalFileldsForEntryAlreadyPresentInCache);
}
if(loading) return "loading...";
return (
  <div>
    <div>author: {data.author}</div>
    {dataDetails.review.map(...
```

... if you really want to join data

```
const ShowDetails = ({data}) => {
   const [bookData, setBookData] = useState(null);
   const { loading, error, data:dataDetails } = useQuery(someQueryAsksAdditionalFileldsForEntryAlreadyPresentInCache, {
    onCompleted: (newData) => {
        setBookData( {...data, ...newData } );
      }
    });
    if(bookData) return ...
      // {bookData.author}
      // bookData.review.map(...
```